# bitbucekt master branch not working while pulling into local

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

i am facing a peculiar issue, while pulling my bitbucket master branch,into my local machine

i am using eclipse git plugin, where i used to pull request from the bitbucket master branch.i have master and branch repositories, and i have merged my branch version into master before doing pull request from the eclipse.

```
 ----master
  ---- branch
```

EDIT (adding more information as per pmr)- flow  (first 4 steps are happens in bitbucket)

```
1. doing changes in branch version
2. sync branch with master, master --sync--> branch.
3. merging branch into master `branch --> master`
4. compared branch --> master ,no difference identified.
5. Fetching master update into my local machine through eclipse-->git repositories-->Fetch from Upstream command
```

my  merge with master from branch was successful, and when i compared my master with branch there were no difference. but when i do pull from my eclipse i am not getting the update master code into my local. i am stilling getting popup saying as below

```
"master updo date no changes"
```

but my master has lot of changes, which i am not getting while pulling or fetch from upstream command from eclipse git view.

i am admin of the repository, i have all access.

thanks for your help

Comment: This is all very confusing. On which branch are you and what changes are you trying to pull? Please give a short description (provide the git commands) of what you did and what you expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have solved this issues, by changing my eclipse bitbucket url from ssh to https, previously i had no team , so it was working with ssh push and pull, later i have added three members to my repository and i changed my credentials into admin and rest as users, after doing this i can only do push from my repository and not pull. i have tried different option , and after changed my repository to https and giving the url as `https://userloginid@bitbucket.org/userloginid/project.git` from ssh url, it started working for me. with https i can do push and pull operations, i have no idean what is difference between ssh vs https push and pull.